# How to write that two specific sets are the same set in first-order naive set theory?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Consider the following true statement

**(1) The set whose only members are the prime numbers between 6 and 12 is the same as the set whose only members are the solutions to the equation x^2-18x+77=0.**

**How do I translate statement (1) above to first-order naive set theory?**

The book I am following seems to define a set as follows: ∃a ∀x (x ∈ a ↔ P(x)).

But doesn't this say rather that a set "a" exists such that its members have the property P?

If I write

∃a ∀x (x ∈ a ↔ Prime(x) & 6<x<12)

∃b ∀x (x ∈ b ↔ x^2-18x+77=0)

My attempt would be:

(∃a ∀x (x ∈ a ↔ Prime(x) & 6<x<12)) & (∃b ∀x (x ∈ b ↔ x^2-18x+77=0)) & a=b

Note that informally (ie outside of FOL) we write {x | P(x)} to mean the same thing as ∃a ∀x (x ∈ a ↔ P(x)).

Thus, informally, I believe statement (1) is {x | Prime(x) & 6<x<12} = {x | x^2-18x+77=0}.

**Is this attempt at translating to first-order naive set theory correct?**

Comment: You don't think this would be more of a MathSE question?

Comment: The question isn't about math. In fact I just completed the course "Language, Proof, and Logic" about first-order logic, and I am now extending my study to the chapter where we apply FOL to a particular domain, in this case set theory. The focus of my question isn't the mathematics, it's the logic. I know way more math than than this question may seem to imply; my lack of knowledge is in the logic foundations. I am asking about FOL and symbolic representation.

Comment: Write each set using set builder notation, and put an equals/ identity sign between them.

Comment: @VinceVickler Is set builder notation part of FOL? I know how to translate statement (1) into math using convenient notation. I am attempting to do it using the underlying language, FOL.

Comment: Not 100% sure exactly what you're using, but even naive set theory is extensional, so I think you should be able to phrase it in terms of x in A iff b in Y.  Since x in A is given predicatively in terms of some predicate a(x), maybe you could do something like A = B iff for all x. a(x) iff b(x)

Comment: You have to write an equality between the two braces-expressions involving the two different formulas

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I was confused when I wrote the question and said I wanted brace notation. I don't want brace notation, I want raw FOL notation.

Comment: Your above set definition ∃a ∀x(x ∈ a ↔ P(x)) seems the axiom scheme of comprehension version of naive set theory, and together with another Axiom of Extensionality ∀a ∀b[∀x(x ∈ a ↔ x ∈ b) → a=b], proves there's a *unique* set conveniently notated by *the* usual set builder satisfying P(x). So you'd better revise your attempt to: ((∃a ∀x (x ∈ a ↔ Prime(x) & 6<x<12)) & (∃b ∀x (x ∈ b ↔ x^2-18x+77=0))) → (a=b) since the extensional equality between a and b is not given premise but can be easily proved via Axiom of Extensionality after exhaustively verified x ∈ a ↔ x ∈ b for all x in either a or b

Comment: A set with brace notation is: A={x | P(x)}. Example: A={x | "x is Even"}.

Comment: Thus, the first set of your example will be A={x | Prime(x) & (6<x<12)} while the second will be B= {x | x^2-18x+77=0}. That's all.

Comment: If you are working into predicate logic (NOT set theory) and thus there is no "in" predicate and no "braces" what you can write is that two "predicates" have the same extension:  ∀x[(Prime(x) & (6<x<12)) ↔ (x^2-18x+77=0)]

Comment: You should be asking this question on math.SE ...

Comment: @evianpring: *user3124634* gave you a sufficient answer. But if you want good answers in general, you should ask on Math SE, not Phil SE. Mathematics includes basic FOL. And if you want to learn foundations of mathematics, you can ask me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77161/basic-mathematics). I actually recommend LPL for complete beginners with no mathematics background, but I actually have a far more practical foundational system that can be used for **all mathematics**, which you might be interested in based on your comments.

Answer (score 2):

No, this does not work. The problem is that a and b are bound to their respective statements. That is, when you say `∃a ∀x (x ∈ a ↔ Prime(x) & 6<x<12)`, you can't invoke 'a' outside of the scope of the existential statement. I don't quite know what the right answer is because I don't know what the notation is for naive set theory. I'm pretty sure that  `∀a∀b((∀x (x ∈ a ↔ Prime(x) & 6<x<12) & ∀x (x ∈ b ↔ x^2-18x+77=0)) → a = b )` is true since conditionals are only ever false if the antecedent is true, and the consequent is false. This is impossible in this scenario, so the statement is true.

Comment: Your answer is as correct as could be expected at the level of the asker. Your criticism of the asker's attempt is also spot on.

Answer (score 0):

∃a∀x(x∈a ⇔ P(x)) says for every property there is a set which includes objects with that property. Basically saying you can have any sort of set you can think of. That's not really a formula for you to follow more of an "axiom".

Naive set−theory has the same logical and non−logical symbols as ZFC with the only difference between the two being that of axioms.

{x|P(x): 6 < x < 12} ={7,11}

You cannot state the above identity in a purely logical language. You need the extralogical bits because "<" is a binary non−logical relation symbol that says something about some set. If you want to do so without involving any particular semantic, then that makes it easy:

P(x): x is prime

G(x,y): x is greater than y

L(x,y): x is less than y

a=6

b=12

c=7

d=11

∀x[((P(x) ∧(G(x,a) ∧ L(x,b))) ⇔ [(x=c ∨ x=d) ∧  ¬(x=c ∧ x=d)]]  you can also split it fi you want but you will be missing ALOT of information in either case. The non−logical symbols are to an extent essential.

I might be missing a clause in the formulation.